# jQuery ssl issues - why do I see hwcdn.net in the response?

Tags: jquery, ssl, ssl-certificate, cdn

I have a project, that uses jQuery CDN, but now I see `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` in Chrome.

Trying to get the jquery file using curl I see a strange domain in error message:

```
curl https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (*.ssl.hwcdn.net) does not match target host name 'code.jquery.com'
```

Is it my system certificate issue or how on earth did another domain get into certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently being resolved by the jquery team.  It appears to be a CDN provider issue.  https://github.com/jquery/codeorigin.jquery.com/issues/34